# How to get Bitrate and FPS statistics with ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to measure statistics (FPS, Bitrate) from a ffplay command instead of ffmpeg. This because recording for many hours takes a lot space on disk.

The way I do it now is that I record a video with ffmpeg for a specific duration and save statistics (-qphist) in a file

Command:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -t $duration -i rtsp://$cred/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264 -qphist -vcodec copy -r 60 -y $outputDIR/camRecording_h264.avi &> $logfile &
```

Instead I would like to play a rtsp video and collect statistics so that video is not saved on disk but still get the same statistics.

Command

```
ffplay "command" &> file
```

With ffplay I can get some info with loglevel but nothing about FPS or Bitrate

I checked man ffplay and googled around but could not find anything about this.

Is it even possible to get FPS and Bitrate statistics from ffplay?

Best regards

Comment: Change `ffmpeg`'s output to `-f null /dev/null`

Comment: When doing this I do not get any bitrate (bitrate=N/A ) only fps. This is nice for FPS but I need bitrate also.